# Is there support for a POP3 client using C# in the .Net Framework?

Tags: c#, .net, pop3, .net-3.5

Is there support for POP3 client in the .net framework?

If so, please tell me it's name as I have been searching for it, but I was unable to find it.

Regards!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Have a look at this project: http://sourceforge.net/projects/hpop/ on SourceForge.

It is a free, open source `.NET Class library in C# for communicating with POP3 Servers(retrieve/delete messages and attachments). Supports decoding files in Base64/QP encoding, including attachemnts, MS-TNEF format, and MS mht file. Compiles on Mono, DotGNU and .NET framework`

Answer (score 13):

A new option (as of 2014) is [MailKit](https://github.com/jstedfast/MailKit) from Xamarin, available under the MIT license.  It parses messages from disk 25x faster than OpenPOP.NET.  It includes support of IMAP, POP3, and SMTP and seems to be very fast and robust.

Comment: This is the library to use in 2022.

Answer (score 3):

No direct support, there are quite a third party options out there commercial and even some free.

I like:
http://www.aspnetpop3.com/

But nowadays there are a lot of alternatives which might be better for your needs (or cost less).

Answer (score 1):

No. Go look at the [Pop3MailClient project](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/Pop3MimeClient.aspx) at CodeProject.

Answer (score 1):

I've tried mailmergelib, Indy.Sockets and [OpenPOP](http://hpop.sourceforge.net/) for a project I just finished, I ended up using OpenPOP.

**mailmergelib**: Was not able to find any documentation on how to download a message with attachements

**Indy.Sockets**: Was able to create a code, but it didn't work with the mails I have. Last version is pretty old.

**OpenPOP**: It just works! It's class has a good and easy logic. Can highly recommend it